# Entity Framework and property containers

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm working on an EF set of data classes and one of the classes is rather large on properties.  However, a number of the properties can be grouped into sub categories and I'd like to do that to help with clarity.  Its also being developed as Code First.

e.g. For an employee, the following is implemented in EF.

```
Public Class Employee

    Public Overridable Property ID As Integer
    Public Overridable Property Surname as String
    Public Overridable Property FirstName as String
    Public Overridable property Age As Byte
    Public Overridable Property StreetAddress as String
    Public Overridable Property Suburb as String
    Public Overridable Property State as String
    Public Overridable Property PostCode As String

End Class
```

All of the data is in a single Employee table.  If I was working with pure classes, then I'd provide a grouping object for all of the employee details, to avoid clutter off the employee, like this:

```
Public Class Employee
    Private cgAddress AS EmployeeAddress

    Public Overridable Property ID As Integer
    Public Overridable Property Surname as String
    Public Overridable Property FirstName as String
    Public Overridable property Age As Byte

    Public ReadOnly Property Address As EmployeeAddress
        Get
            If cgAddress Is Nothing Then
                cgAddress = New EmployeeAddress
                ' Any population.
            End If

            Return cgAddress
        End Get
    End Property 

End Class

Public Class EmployeeAddress

    Public Overridable Property StreetAddress as String
    Public Overridable Property Suburb as String
    Public Overridable Property State as String
    Public Overridable Property PostCode As String

End Class
```

I can't seem to find similar questions anywhere (possibly due to lack of searching knowledge), so my question is this:

Is this even possible to configure under EF without having a separate Address table, and if so, how are the mappings configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further reading into Complex Types answers this question for me.  It doesn't give me the further step of collections, but it solved the grouping issue.

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/04/01/making-complex-types-useful.aspx
http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-2-complex-types